# Jest can't mock returned value of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Given the below code, I have two functions in main.js which I export and I want to test that `getChangedItems` returns the correct string given that I pass it a html element. I want to mock the return value of `theChanger` so that I don't have to worry about the `getBoundingClientRect();` error blow.

`TypeError: itemData.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

main.js

```
export const theChanger = (itemData) => {
 const { top: parentTop, left: parentLeft } = itemData.getBoundingClientRect();
...

    return { isFull: true, isPartial: true};
}

export const getChangedItems = (itemData) => {
    let items = '';
    const changeIdicator = theChanger(itemData); // I want to mock the return value of this
    if(changeIdicator.isFull || changeIdicator.isPartial) {
        let items = "I made it";
    }
   return items
}
```

main-test.js

```
import { theChanger, getChangedItems } from './main.js';
test('getChangedItems returns correct data', () =>  {
    const htmlElement = '<div>Some element</div>'

    expect(getChangedItems(htmlElement)).toBe("I made it")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string

```
 const htmlElement = '<div>Some element</div>'
```

it is not actually HTML element. So it does not have method `getBoundingClientRect` method either.

Maybe you might somehow use JSDOM's `createElement` to create element. But I believe for testing purpose it's even better to construct object with mocking just part of HTMLElement properties.

Just like that:

```
const htmlElement = {
    getBoundingClientRect: {top: <what you need>, left: <what you need>}
    ... any other methods expected
}
```

Why this is better than using actual HTMLElement constructor? Since you are testing some concrete module not DOM rendering engine itself you don't have to keep this entry with complete and consistent data. It's easier to mock only that you need. It's more clear what your module actually needs by looking at that mock. And you may provide mock that would be near to impossible to get by using `createElement`(say, `getBoundingClientRect` can return `top: Infinity`).

Comment: This makes total sense, but wouldn't it be easier if I mock the return value of `theChanger(itemData)` as per my question, because I will test that function separately. I care what `getChangedItems` returns?

Comment: @Mohammed, I don't see it's possible to mock one function from file while using another without mocking. See long thread https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936